# Setup test data for Jmeter and Junit

Tags: java, junit, jmeter

Is there any way I can setup my test data for load tests that use Jmeter and Junit? I would like to be able to do something like get a  new user from a csv for each thread of a test.

Comment: I have not used jmeter before, but I know that for junit you can use the setUp() method for that kind of things, like opening files, setups, loading/reseting configurations and so on. That method will be executed before the tests start being executed. Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah I know man, but let's say I have a list of predefined users that I want to loop through and log in with. I'm not sure how to do that in setUp with Jmeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've used this a number of times.

See [JMeter : Reading variables from a file](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/jmeter-reading-variables-from-file.html).

Answer (score 1):

jMeter is an load testing framework based on HTTP. It can simulate multiple users using your website. So there is no concept of setup data. What you can essentially do is do some script to load massive data to load or use one request to store some details and other to retrieve it back. When doing jUnit testing, to load data, you can use [dbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) which can load data for you before testing it.

Comment: Jmeter lets you load CSV files and set user defined variables. It also lets you use Junit which has setup and tear down. Even more, you can define a Junit test runner. Jmeter uses its own implementation of Junit. To say Jmeter has no concept of  setup data seems misleading to me.

Comment: The CSV file is to load setup data to use for test cases not load the data to test against...

Comment: Yeah I know man, that's totally what I want to do. I just don't know if it's possible to use data read through CSV by Jmeter, in my Junit tests. I want to be able to read the CSV once to prepare my test data, and then run everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a CSV dataset to only be read once, but having only ONE row of data in it.

This will work with JUnit, as the following happens: Junit opens Jmeter script and executes JMeter script.  The Jmeter script, when executed, reads from the CSV file, populates all defined data fields and then runs the requests